# Azure AD B2C not showing logins for custom app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

Currently using Azure AD B2C as our authentication provider and we have a requirement to access logs of all user login activity for our custom application.

If I navigate to the B2C portal, Users>Sign-in logs I only see sign ins for Application of type "Azure Portal"?

Is there anything that needs to be enabled for a custom app registered in the "App registrations" section to see this activity?

Comment: Did you look in the audit logs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/view-audit-logs

Comment: It shows operations of type authentication, but it doesn't show the username or application that was being authenticated directly. Instead it shows targetTenant, correlationId etc

Comment: I'm in the same boat, I'm using social login only, with a custom OpenId IdP. The audit logs are empty

Answer (score 0):

You can't see user sign-ins for individual Azure AD B2C applications under the Users section of the Azure Active Directory or Azure AD B2C pages in the Azure portal. The sign-in events there show user activity.

For Workound You can check the users login to your custome app using filter the Application Name.

**AZureADB2C->User->SigninLogs**

Like I have shown in below Picture.

[image]
[image]